# CSS include in a JSP doesn't work

Tags: css, jsp, jakarta-ee, include

I tried to include a CSS file in a JSP for my java project.
The problem is that the first solution is working well but not the second solution and I want to use the second. Does anyone have any solution ?

Arborescence :

--WEB-INF
|
|
|
    -> bootstrap
    -> css
    -> font
    -> js
    -> jsp files

first :

```
<style type="text/css"> -->
    <%@include file="css/footer.css" %> --%>
</style>
```

Second :

```
<link href="css/footer.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The key word here is refering the **"relative path"** to the file you want to access.
your css folder and jspfiles folder are siblings... what i mean by that is you are trying to give relative path to the css file in reference to your jsp file. for example if your structure looks like this,

--WEB-INF
|
|
|
-> bootstrap
-> font
-> js
-> jsp files
->CSS
   | _ _footer.css
->jsp files
   | _ _ index.jsp

the footer.css file is one folder up and over to the index.jsp file. Hence "../" will do the trick.

Now if the css folder is in the webapp root directory, then "/css" will refer to that folder.

so try

```
<link href="../css/footer.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

or

```
<link href="/css/footer.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

hope this helps

Comment: I thanks for your reply. Sorry I didn't explain my ideas properly, All JSP files are not in a directory. If I take your example "index.jsp" is directly in the folder WEB-INF